# Busca Datas com Diferença Definida em SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, microsoft

Como realizar uma consulta no MICROSOFT SQL SERVER que diante uma quantidade dias definido  retorna somente as datas que se encontra com essa diferença existente. por exemplo

Em uma tabela ter as seguintes datas cadastradas:

```
02/01/2018
06/01/2018
08/01/2018
15/01/2018
21/01/2018
26/01/2018
28/01/2018
```

E o período estiver definido como **4 dias** ele mostre somente as datas que tem a diferença entre **4 dias**.

**Resultado esperado :**

```
02/01/2018
06/01/2018
08/01/2018
26/01/2018
28/01/2018
```

Comment: @ClaytoFelippe O que solicita é retornar somente as linhas em que a diferença de datas entre a data da linha e a data da linha seguinte (ou anterior) esteja no intervalo informado? // Qual é a versão do SQL Server?

Comment: se a pergunta foi respondida, por favor, marcar a resposta como correta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo exemplo de resultado deduz-se que a consulta deve retornar todas as linhas em que a diferença de datas entre a linha atual e a linha anterior ou posterior esteja dentro do intervalo.

Eis sugestão que atende a este requisito:

```
-- código #1
declare @Intervalo int;
set @Intervalo= 4;

with tabela_S as (
SELECT DataX,
       seq= row_number() over (order by DataX)
  from tbDatas
)
SELECT T1.DataX 
  from tabela_S as T1
       left join tabela_S as T2 
                 on T2.seq = T1.seq -1
       left join tabela_S as T3 
                 on T3.seq = T1.seq +1
  where datediff(day, T2.DataX, T1.DataX) <= @Intervalo
        or datediff(day, T1.DataX, T3.DataX) <= @Intervalo;
```

Substitua `DataX` pelo nome da coluna que contém a data e `tbDatas` pelo nome da tabela.

Eis o código que gerou a massa de dados para testes:

```
-- código #2
CREATE TABLE tbDatas (DataX date);

INSERT into tbDatas values
  (convert(date, '02/01/2018', 103)),
  (convert(date, '06/01/2018', 103)),
  (convert(date, '08/01/2018', 103)),
  (convert(date, '15/01/2018', 103)),
  (convert(date, '21/01/2018', 103)),
  (convert(date, '26/01/2018', 103)),
  (convert(date, '28/01/2018', 103));
```

Answer (score -1):

O melhor resultado que consigo ver é o seguinte:

```
DECLARE @IntervaloEmDias INT
SELECT  @IntervaloEmDias = 4

SELECT 
    TB1.DIA
FROM 
    NOME_TABELA TB1
INNER JOIN
    NOME_TABELA TB2 ON TB1.DIA <> TB2.DIA 
WHERE 
    ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, TB1.DATA, TB2.DATA)) <= @IntervaloEmDias 
GROUP BY
    TB1.DIA
```